# ¿Cómo poner un select option en un input?

Tags: html, select

Verán tengo esto:

```html
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?=$r->Name?>" disabled="disabled">
```

Me funciona bien lo que hace es mostrarme uno de los nombres de 1 cuenta , ahora cual es el problema? es que una cuenta puede tener hasta 4 nombres , y el código solo me muestra uno, eh probado con un `option` para que me muestre los 4 nombres , y si me funciono me muestra los 4 nombres (el $r->CID diferencia al id de cada nombre de una misma cuenta)

```html
<select name="id"><option value="<?=$r->CID?>"><?=$r->Name?></option></select>
```

El problema esta en como enlazarlo con ese `input` y que modifique solo el que esta seleccionado

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer, trata de explicarte mejor, y todo lo que sea código no lo pongas en imagen, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas plantear mejor tu pregunta, haz el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas más sobre el sitio y ganes tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Cada cuenta puede tener hasta 4 nombres, cierto? y cada uno de ellos tiene un id?

Comment: @DaxTter77 si cada uno tiene su id

Comment: Entonces, coloca bien el bloque de código en dónde llenas el `select`, recuerda no ponerlo como imagén, copíalo y pegalo en la pregunta, en las ayudas que te aparecen a la derecha se te explica como encerrar un bloque de código en una pregunta

Comment: Así te puedo ayudar más

Comment: @DaxTter77 ya esta creo

Comment: Los registros los traes de una base de datos, no? para llenar no haces un ciclo?

Comment: si esta en una base de datos

Comment: Y lo que quieres es qué? que te mande esos datos al input para poder modificarlos?

Comment: lo que quiero es que el nombre que esta selecionado en el <option> sea el que se modifique

Comment: Bien, ya te respondo lo que tengo hasta ahora, ya me dirás que te parece y si te funciona

Comment: Listo, revisalo

Comment: @DaxTter77 gracias si me funciono

Comment: Me alegra mucho, amigo, recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta, suerte con tu proyecto, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea que tengo es que, cuando llenas el `select` en el `value` mandas ya el `id` que tiene dicho nombre, entonces, hay que hacer, que a lo que elija un nombre llene dos inputs, uno que sea el del nombre como tal, y el otro que sea el del id, que este estará oculto. Lo que haremos será en `JavaScript`

`HTML`

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="" disabled="disabled">
<select name="nombres" id="nombres" onchange="llenarInputs()"><option value="<?=$r->CID?>"><?=$r->Name?></option></select>
```

`JS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function llenarInputs(){
      nombreSelec = document.getElementeById("nombres");
      id = document.getElementeById("id");      
      nombre = document.getElementeById("nombre");

      id.value = nombreSelec.value;
      nombre.value = nombreSelec.options[nombreSelec.selectedIndex].text;
      nombre.disabled = false;
   }
</script>
```

Algo así sería, alguna duda o sugerencia, me la comentas, espero que te sirva, saludos!!